# Running PestPHP test cases in Laravel + PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am trying to run a test case made with PestPHP in a project that using Laravel and PostgreSQL as it's database.

I normally use Laravel + MySQL so I do not know what to do in this situation.

Here's my test case.

```
it('should not edit a game title if another game has the same title', function () {
    $contentManagerService = app(ContentManagerService::class);
    $existingGame = Game::factory()->create();
    $targetGame = Game::factory()->create();

    $editGameTitleResults = $contentManagerService
    ->setid($targetGame->id)
    ->setTitle($existingGame->title)
    ->editGameTitle();

    expect($editGameTitleResults)->toBeString();

    $actualGameRecord = Game::where('id', $targetGame->id)->get()->first();
    expect($actualGameRecord->title)->toBe($targetGame->title);
});
```

The `$editGameTitleResults` is supposed to be a string at this test case since the insert method for the game record would throw an exception which would be caught by my application and would return the exception message as a string which is working as intended but If I wanted to double check the game record if it was changed, my test runner now returns an exception.

This test case works on a project made with Laravel + MySQL but when I use PostgreSQL as my database. It now throws an exception

> SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I am using the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase::class`.

Am I doing something wrong or I do need to rewrite my test, if so can you suggest me a way on how I can rewrite the test for such behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did not find any solutions to my problem that makes use of the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase::class` I instead opted to use a different trait which caused a slight performance issue but still works.

The trait that I used is  `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations::class`